# if statement syntax error when attempting to embed meta tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

```
<%= if @meta_leeds == "leeds" %>
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.some.link/to/image"/>
<% end %>
```

I want to embed a specific meta tag only on one page of my rails application. I defined :

```
@meta_leeds = "leeds"
```

in the pages' controller and it will display the string when put between a h1 tag but it will not output the meta tag based on the outcome of the above  if statement.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `<% if @meta_leeds == "leeds" %>` - you don't need to output the `if` statement

Comment: It still gives a syntax error. i've changed the code to :

`<% @meta_leeds == "leeds" %><meta property="og:image" content="http://www.some.link/to/image"/><% end %>`

Comment: What's the syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if @meta_leeds == "leeds" %>
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.some.link/to/image"/>
<% end %>
```

Just remove the `=` (and only the `=`) from the statement.

Comment: Great, this seems to have worked! But i'm confused as I thought ' = ' was meant for assigning a value to a variable and ' == ' was a comparison operator. Why does this work as a definition operator rather than a comparison operator?

Comment: @LouisJones It doesn't, you're confusing erb and Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to embed the meta tag by checking the title rather than if the variable that was in a controller function was present.

Here is the final working code :

```
<% if yield(:title) == "Leeds" %>
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.some.link/to/image"/>
<% end %>
```